# How to get data from custom dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I have created a custom dialog class(extended it with Dialog) with 3 buttons, and each button must call a different activity. I seem to be having problems with calling the activity onClick.

```
private class OKListener implements android.view.View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dismiss();
        Intent myintent = new Intent(myapp.this,nextAct.class)
        startActivity(myintent);
        }

    }
}
```

What am I missing?
Can you give me specific examples on how to call an activity from a custom Dialog class? I would really appreciate it much! I am already desperate after going through the whole night without much sleep.

I followed this tutorial by the way: [How to display custom dialog in Android](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example/)

~Ciao

Answer (score 0):

In onclick you have to check,which button is click and then load the intent according to the button click.
 something like this

```
dismiss();
  if (v== firstButton)
    {
       Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ButtonOne.class);
       startActivity(i);
    }
    if (v == cancelButton)  
    {
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ButtonTwo.class);
       startActivity(i);

    }
```

Hope this is useful

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

It shows how you can customize the AlertDialog (which basically already meets all your needs: three buttons, custom layout, etc).

Especially note the **Creating a Custom Dialog** paragraph a bit down the page.